# Extremely simple question about not initalizing reference

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, initialization

```
class Token_stream {
public:
    Token get();                // get a Token
    void putback(Token t);      // put a token back
    void ignore(char c);        // discard characters up to and including a c
    Token_stream(istream& ii) : is{ii} { }
private:
    bool full { false };        // is there a Token in the buffer?
    Token buffer {'0'};         // here is where putback() stores a Token
    istream& is;
};
```

`is` a reference but when it's created it doesn't really refer anything does it? Why does this work then? Is it because the constructor makes `is` refer to `ii`?

Comment: Yes, you initialize ```is``` with ```ii```

Comment: `is` doesn't exist, before constructor starts. Constructor is what creates `is`

Comment: Another tiny question, here in my code this doesn't run because it says I need a default constructor but when I run this code: https://github.com/Chrinkus/stroustrup-ppp/blob/master/chapter08/ex01_calculator.cpp which seems to have the exact same code in Token_stream it runs just fine? Why does it ask me to put in a default constructor but not in the code on github?

Comment: Nvm got it my bad I just realized he never creates an object with no parameters he only creates Token_stream objects with a constructor that uses the istream parameter but in my code I create objects with no arguments

Answer (score 2):

The reference is created in the constructor in its mem-initializer list

```
Token_stream(istream& ii) : is{ii} { }
                            ^^^^^^
```

Within the class definition the declaration of the reference

```
istream& is;
```

is present that the compiler would know what is the type of the name `is` and reserve enough memory for an object of the class.